# Can we use one service to do multiple tasks in android?

Tags: android, performance, service, android-service

I am new to Android. I am very confused in writing services for my application. I have three background Jobs.

- Sync Contacts and update the local database.
- Sync NewsFeed of User and add new posts to local database.
- Sync Comments for a specific post

I want to write a service which can do all three tasks. But i can call them whenever i want separately or all together.

For example,  When app starts i want to sync just NewsFeed and Contacts. But during the use of app. I just want to call sync comments for a specific post. How will i call these different task using onStartCommand() ?

Is this possible to write in one service? 
Or i have to write three different services for these tasks ? 
Will performance be affected by writing too many services ?

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want a [sync adapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Comment: Will sync Adapter provide me the Status of my background job like services do with receivers ?? And will they be running on different thread ??? @GeorgeMulligan

Comment: It does run on a different thread. I don't remember there being a built in way to do status updates but you could send updates yourself. You can do what you want by extending `Service` also but the sync adapter can make things simpler in some cases because it does handle some things for you. Give the doc a look and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: ok @GeorgeMulligan Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I have read the docs and what i get from it ----- I will be creating a sync adapter and a service for it. I don't get what Authenticator Service is ????  and also didn't found helpful regarding giving status to my UI components regarding sync ??? Can you provide me some tutorial ?? And also the important thing is that i will be writing three Sync Adapters ??

Comment: you can even use one broadcast receiver to run your whole app. draw a good app structure and you will see that everything will sink it sir